# How to hide all pages [published: false] by default

Tags: jekyll

I would like to hide all pages in my Jekyll repo by default. I distribute my repo to two locations, one private which has authorisation and another which is public. For the public, I build with a _config.public.yaml which has the below snippet. The idea is, if I put a front matter field of `published: true` on a specific page it will take precedence and be published. Whereas the rest of the pages will never be built.

This is the _config.public.yaml file I use to build the public site.

```
yaml
include: 
    - .htaccess
    - _pages
defaults:
    - scope:
        path: "_pages"
      values:
        permalink: /:path/:basename:output_ext
        published: false
```

Comment: Does @nick 's edit resolved you problem ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel all I did was make the post easier to read. The question still needs an answer.

Comment: Are you sure path: '_pages' is correct?

Comment: yes, created to house pages, and in the include section.

Answer (score 0):

Using " published: false ", is only possible in a DOCUMENT's front matter.

If you don't want a collection to output a page for each document in you collection, set " output: false " for your collection. (default is true)

```
collections:
  pages:
    output: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am working on pages rather than posts, so _drafts and future options will not apply to my problem. However, I have tried the `bundle exec jekyll server --unpublished` command and it seemed to have no effect. Pages with `published: true` in the front matter were published as well as ones without any specified `published:` frontmatter var. Was the expected outcome that the default be set to `published: false` ?

Comment: Have you tried puttin "published: false" in the frontmatter of the page? I took a look [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6958), and it seems like it should work for custom collections.

Comment: changing the front matter on a per page bases will certainly work. But at 600 pages this becomes untenable. Especially since I publish to a public and private site on commit. As mentioned earlier the public site has its own _config.yml which I am trying to get to not publish pages without an explicit `published: true` . I will no doubt have to do a pre build function iterate through all pages and set `published: false` if it does not exist. But was hoping config would help.

Comment: As for collections, yes you can unpublish collections by default, however, the entire structure still exists `_pages` and duplicated to `/collection_name` where it only produces the `published: true` pages. I also keep the graphics for each page inline which collections does not play well with. For example PageOne.md has a PageOne.img/ the folder at the same level. Whereas Collections expects all to be put away in /assets or somesuch. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Okay, so what I get from this is that you are keeping two seperate folders, with the "same" files, but on you don't want published, and the other you want published.
An option is to try "exclude", exclude: [DIR, FILE, ...]

You can read more [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/).

If that does not work, try "output: false", as seen [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/)